# How do i make or customize the title bars size small in Ubuntu themes?

Tags: themes, customization, titlebar

[image: My Ubuntu terminal]

As you can see the title bar of the terminal is quite wide and takes a lot of space.

[image: Mac Terminal]

I like the way Mac's terminal or its window's title bars are narrow.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and using "whiteSur-dark-solid" theme.

Comment: Ask this question from the author of the whiteSur theme. You can reach them probably from where you have downloaded that theme.

Answer (score 1):

In general, using apps which do not use CSD can help you reduce the titlebar size. Usually the MATE apps use traditional menus instead of CSD.

For example, you can use `mate-terminal` instead of `gnome-terminal`. GNOME Terminal uses CSD, which takes up a lot of vertical space, whereas `mate-terminal` uses a traditional menu.

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends mate-terminal
```

[image]

<sup>MATE Terminal</sup>

Then change the default terminal with the following command, and choose `mate-terminal` there.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```